# Discord.js Get common servers between two users

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am looking to get the common servers between two discord `User`s. Currently, my bot is able to access the guilds that it is a part of, however given a user who has sent it a message, it is unable to access any of the guilds of the user. I understand that discord limits you to seeing shared guilds/servers, but I can't find any way to even access those.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Context: DM

```
guild = message.client.guilds.cache.find(clientGuild=>message.author.????)
```

I want something like:

```
guild = message.client.guilds.cache.find(clientGuild=>message.author.guilds.includes(clientGuild)
```

Comment: You can't do that unless your bot is in the specified guilds. Fortunately, you can use an OAuth2 scope called "guilds". That'll allow you to see all guilds of a user, but for that, you'll need a web server.

Answer (score 4):

**This will not work with sharding**. I don't have experience with sharding yet, so I'll leave it for someone else with experience.

### To get guilds the current user and the user that sent the message

You can either try to use the cached members (and pray that the user is cached, which should be the case if the user sent a message but isn't guaranteed) or fetch the member.

#### The naive way using cache:

The guild object has a [member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) method to get the member object from user. You can simply check that it's not undefined to see if the user is in the guild and **is cached**.

```js
client.guilds.cache.filter(guild => !!guild.member(message.author));
```

#### The longer way using fetch

This will fetch the members, so with bots with high guild count may hit rate limits (check the documentation [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits)).

```js
var guilds = Promise.all(
    client.guilds.cache.map(async guild => [
        guild.id,
        await guild.members.fetch(message.author).catch(() => null))
    ])
).then(guilds => guilds.filter(g => g[1]).map(guild => client.guilds.resolve(guild[0]));
```

It works by trying to fetch the member from every guild the bot is in (the [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) may fail so there's a catch which just returns null) and then filtering the guilds based on the result. There's no async filter on the [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) class, so instead I map to async predicates which I then await them using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

### Sharding

If you need sharding, it should be possible to do the same using broadcastEval, but I'm not confident enough to write it yet.