# How to find mutual servers & present it in Discord.js Bot's Select Menu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, command

I am having a lot of trouble finding relevant documentation regarding how to find mutual server of interaction.user & bot.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827582/discord-js-get-common-servers-between-two-users) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847540/get-all-guild-ids-with-discord-js) too, but no luck.

This is the code

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token } = require('../config.json');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu, Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('transfer-bans')
        .setDescription('Transfers Bans across servers'),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const emb = {
            description:'Guild fetcher',
        };
        const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS], partials: ['CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });


        const guilds = await client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
        console.log(guilds);

        const guilds2 = Promise.all(
            client.guilds.cache.map(async guild => [
                guild.id,
                await guild.members.fetch(interaction.member).catch(() => null),
            ]),
        ).then(guilds2 => guilds2.filter(g => g[1]).map(guild => client.guilds.resolve(guild[0])));
        console.log(guilds2);

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageSelectMenu()
                    .setCustomId('select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                    .addOptions([
                        {
                            label: 'me',
                            description: 'description',
                            value: 'option_first',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'me too',
                            description: ' description',
                            value: 'option_second',
                        },
                    ]),
            );
        await interaction.reply({ embeds:[emb], components: [row] });

    },
};
```

All I get in console.log is -

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Tue Oct 19 2021
Ready! Logged in as Ban Utlis#6717
MRDGH2821#7746 in #general triggered an interaction.
[]
Promise { <pending> }
```

My question is,

<strike>Q1.1. How do I fetch a list of guildIDs of all guilds in which my bot is present?

*OR*

Q1.2. How do I find mutual servers with respect to `interaction.user`?</strike>

Q2. How do I present the mutual servers dynamically in the [select menu](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#select-menus) of the bot's message
 Check Edit 2

I'm using Discord.js v13. I even looked up their guide & documentation regarding mutual servers & nothing was found.

Bot source code hsted at [GitHub](https://github.com/MRDGH2821/Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot)

###### Edit 1

The implementation of fetching Bot's guild IDs in this code have no syntactical issue. The issue is, there is no guild IDs being printed to console.log

###### Edit 2

I got help from this [Pull Request](https://github.com/MRDGH2821/Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot/pull/2)

So here is a part of updated code:

```js
const guilds = [];
        for (const [, guild] of interaction.client.guilds.cache) {
            await guild.members.fetch(interaction.user).then(() => guilds.push(guild)).catch(error => console.log(error));
        }

        const servers = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(guilds).length;i++) {
            servers.push({ label: Object.entries(guilds)[i][1].name, value:Object.entries(guilds)[i][1].id });
        }

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageSelectMenu()
                    .setCustomId('select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                    .addOptions(servers),
            );
        await interaction.editReply({ embeds:[emb], components: [row] });
```

So this fixed the guild fetching issue.

I even managed to present it into Select Menu.
Which now brings to my 3rd question (Although the above given code snippet is the actual answer to title of this post)

<strike>Q3. Any guides on how to recieve interactions from select menu?</strike>

The discordjs [guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#interaction-collectors) on recieveing select menu interactions is not working in my context.

###### Edit 3

I felt it would be better to ask Q3 in seperate post rather than this.

Comment: Loop through all the servers your bot is in and check if the user is in each

Comment: @MrMythical I did think about it, but the issue with my implementation is I'm not getting any guild IDs in console.log(). So I don't have any "iterable" to loop through

Comment: Use `client.guilds.cache`?

Comment: I did. 1st implementation simply returns this - `[ ]`. 2nd implementation returns a promise which I don't know how to work on

Comment: Use `async-await`. Like to console log `guilds2` when it's resolved you simply write `console.log(await guilds2)`

Comment: This question is around 4 questions in one. Please only ask one question per StackOverflow post. I see that you are asking Q3 in a separate post, which is the right move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer is in Edit 2 of the question, reposting it would certainly help.

I got help from this [Pull Request](https://github.com/MRDGH2821/Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot/pull/2)

And here is the full working code which fetches mutual servers from `interaction.user` & displays them in the select menu component.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token } = require('../config.json');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu } = require('discord.js');
const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('transfer-bans')
        .setDescription('Transfers Bans across servers'),

    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.deferReply('Fetching Guilds');
        const emb = {
            description:'Guild fetcher',
        };

//code to fetch mutual servers
        const guilds = [];
        for (const [, guild] of interaction.client.guilds.cache) {
            await guild.members.fetch(interaction.user).then(() => guilds.push(guild)).catch(error => console.log(error));
        }

//code to generate array of server names & IDs for .addOption() in select menu component
        const servers = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(guilds).length;i++) {
            servers.push({ label: Object.entries(guilds)[i][1].name, value:Object.entries(guilds)[i][1].id });
        }

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageSelectMenu()
                    .setCustomId('select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Choose a Server')
                    .addOptions(servers),
            );
        await interaction.editReply({ embeds:[emb], components: [row] });
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that would be:

```
<client>.guilds.cache.filter((u) => u.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id))
```

then of course you will need to map it

`<client>.guilds.cache.filter((u) => u.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id)).map((g) => g.id) // will map guilds by ID`

`<client>.guilds.cache.filter((u) => u.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id)).map((g) => g.name) // will map guilds by name`

Comment: It did help in fetching guilds, but this method wasn't much reliable. My bot was in 4 servers but it fetched ID of only 1 (i.e. where i executed the command)